# AppCompat AlertDialog radio button gravity / positioning

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

Google's design specs for dialogs show examples where radio buttons in single choice dialogs are positioned to the left from text [dialog-specs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs) Does anyone have an idea how to position the radio buttons like in these examples? 
When using AppCompat AlertDialog from 22.2.1 and the following code, I always get them positioned at the right end

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Choose category")
.setSingleChoiceItems(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"}, -1, 
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    }
})
.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    }
})
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    }
}).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use this library:

https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

You can fing here all kinds of dialogs: EditText, single choice, wiht rwo or three action buttons etc.

I hope this would help you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
However in order to use material-dialogs we need to do a bringup on api 23 first, which is not possible at the moment as we have to replace all of our apache http libs too.

Answer (score 0):

Made a simple test project with the above code, on API 22 the radio buttons appear right aligned, but on the API 23, with the very same code, they appear left aligned. Seems like there's a change of default radio button alignment in the AppCompat itself.